# To integrate Twitter Tweets on my Website

Tags: twitter

Is there any API or any methods to integrate the twitter tweet box on the website by the screen names only ? (Without using the Twitter Widgets)

Answer (score 0):

There is no need of API here. Just login with your twitter account goto settings tab and click on Widgets.

Here click on "Create New" you can see preview on right side of your page.

Here's [Twitter Widget link](http://www.bourncreative.com/how-to-add-the-official-twitter-widget-to-your-website/) They mention step by step process. I think it is useful for u.